# How to calculate the estimated time of arrival and control signal between two quaternion?

Tags: unity, quaternion, automation

I'm trying to wrap my head around a control algorithm for a space game. If the user sets a target rotation I want to get a ETA counter and show the engine output. The only input to the system is a max delta angular velocity around the space ship local axis.

I uses Unity engine so I ave access to the quaternion of the rotation and global angular velocity. I can find the delta rotation between the two points as it's dQ = Qstart^-1*Qtarget (from Qstart*dQ=Qtarget).

But how Do I find the engine parameter at that frame and what is the ETA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking how to determine the time it takes to rotate from one orientation to another at a certain rate. That is a very simple equation, commonly known as Distance = Speed x Time. Your Distance is the angle between the two rotations. Your Speed is the "max delta angular velocity." Knowing those two, you can solve for Time.

I suggest that you refer to the documentation for [Quaternion](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html), [Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html), and [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html). Quaternion.Angle will provide the difference in degrees without needing to do the math yourself. Quaternion.Slerp could be used to actually rotate the ship transform, but there are other ways to do so. Calculate this during the Update method of a MonoBehaviour. Displaying the ETA to the user can be done minimally with GUI.Label during OnGUI method, but making it look nice is another challenge entirely.

If you need something more, please clarify your question. It is worded strangely. What do you mean by "show the engine output" and "find the engine parameter"?

Comment: Thank you! What I mean is that the ship has a max angular velocity acceleration along each of the ships axis. This is the control which I want to affect the ship. I understand that I need to do a acceleration and deceleration along the shortest path. I belive my question left is. How do I rotate target direction to the ships local rotation?

Comment: @user1814859 Ok, if you need to process each axis separately, I would suggest using Vector3 and Transform.InverseTransformDirection. You can also rotate vectors with * operator, if a Quaternion object is the left operand. However, rotating on 3 separate local Euler axes can be tricky, because a different order can change the result.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I did a lot of progress on my understanding of the problem but I have refined my question some more since i did get stuck on one step. I made it a seperate question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93634/how-to-align-angular-velocity-wit-target-rotation-in-3d